# Gnuplot: speed up plotting or export 3-d figure

Tags: gnuplot

I have more than 1.5 million scalar values on the sphere. Each of them is plotted as a point with color corresponding to the value. For the whole 1.5 million points, rendering takes so much time it is virtually impossible to rotate the sphere (it lags a couple of seconds).

- Is there a way to speed up the plotting?

I have used, e.g., `every 10` so far, but now I really need to see all points at once.

- Is it possible to export something like a 3-d bitmap with a high resolution?

Whatever format is possible, such that the image can then be viewed and rotated quickly, probably in another program.

Comment: Hold the `Ctrl` key while you rotate, the plot is redrawn only after you release the key

Comment: Sometimes there's an easy way... Thank you!